# Rearrange list based on key WITHOUT sorting

Tags: python, algorithm, list, data-structures

I have a list of tuples `(x, ind)` where `x` is the item and `ind` is it's target index in the resulting list. The list is in random order, but it can be assumed that if there are `N` items in the list, the values of `ind` in the tuples will be in `[0,N)` without repetition (i.e. all the valid indices will exist exactly once). How do I get a list where each tuple's position is `ind`?

**Please do not confuse with the many existing answers of how to sort by key.**

Obviously, sorting by the `ind` key is easy, but there would be the unnecessary extra `O(n*logn)` cost to what should be a `O(n)` operation because of the aforementioned assumption about `ind` values.

So:

```
l = [('item1',1), ('item0',0), ('item2',2), ('item4',4), ('item3',3)]
l2 = magic_rearrange(l, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(l2)
```

Should give:

```
[('item0',0), ('item1',1), ('item2',2), ('item3',3), ('item4',4)]
```

Comment: That's still sorting, but without the `sorted` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your indices are unique, here's one way. You can initialise a new list and just insert elements in their right position.

```
def magic_rearrange(l1):
    l2 = [None] * len(l1)
    for i in l1:
        l2[i[1]] = i
    return l2
```

And a demo:

```
>>> l = [('item1',1), ('item0',0), ('item2',2), ('item4',4), ('item3',3)]
>>> magic_rearrange(l)
[('item0', 0), ('item1', 1), ('item2', 2), ('item3', 3), ('item4', 4)]
```

---

There's a quicker way to do this, if you use `numpy`'s fancy indexing.

```
import numpy as np
def magic_rearrange(l1):
    l2 = np.repeat(None, len(l1))
    l2[[x[1] for x in l1]] = l1
    return l2
```

And a demo:

```
>>> magic_rearrange(l)
array([('item0', 0), ('item1', 1), ('item2', 2), ('item3', 3), ('item4', 4)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Damn you beat me to it, nice.

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't consider a different key. Although it probably solves the problem for OP :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani Yep... if OP really needed the key, I'd back your solution anyday.

Comment: Nice. Can you suggest a comprehension that'll have the same effect?

Comment: @Stav With this technique? Not that I know of. :) A comprehension will create elements and append them in sequence. There's no way I know of random insertion in a list comprehension. So, you wouldn't be able to achieve this with a comprehension unless  of course you presorted the first list!

Comment: @Coldspeed understood, how about an approach where you would use comprehension along with indexing, so like `l[some_magic]` to get `l2`?

Comment: Yes. If you use `numpy`. Wait a sec, will paste a solution here.

Comment: @Stav Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create the list first and then replace:

```
def magic_rearrange(l, key):
   # creates list to not change original list
   new_list = list(l)
   # reorder on new list
   for original_index, new_index in enumerate(map(key, l)):
       new_list[new_index] = l[original_index]
   return new_list
```

Comment: You should add a default argument for completeness!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
def magic_rearrange (input_list, key = lambda x: x):
    result_list = [None] * len (input_list)
    for p in input_list:
        result_list[key (p)] = p
    return result_list
```

We just create a list of the desired length, and then put each element in its place.
The order of operations can be arbitrary, but each element will eventually get to its position in the resulting list.
This is O(N) if copying a single list element and obtaining the key are both O(1).
The `key = lambda x: x` is for the default order, which is comparing the whole elements (however useless since the result is just `list(range(N))`).